# Recover from deleting lines in gvim

Tags: vim

I deleted some lines in a text file with gvim (`ma`, <move cursor>, `` d`a ``), saved and closed gvim. I realized I'd deleted the wrong lines, and opened a new gvim and opened the file, but 'p' did not re-paste the cut lines. The backup file had the version with lines deleted (presumably when I reopened the file it deleted the previous backup).

Is there any way of recovering the missing lines? I have windows 7 and have got shadow copies turned off for the volume.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `undofile` option in your `.vimrc`:

```
:set udf
```

Answer (score 1):

With Vim 7.3, if you had `:set undofile` (*persistent undo*), you could have simply pressed `u` to undo.

Too bad that `p` didn't work; you could still manually check the `_viminfo` file for the lost contents.

I hope you use this occasion to rethink your backup strategy, various revision control systems are available and quite simple to use. For file system locations where this is not feasible, I use a lightweight alternative in the form of the [writebackup plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1828).